# Animating Number needs to be stop with in 60 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

The number is animating from **start(1,000)** to **end(10,000)**. But I want this animation to be stop within some predefined time such as 60 second. **end value** can be large i.e. **23,600,191** but this animation needs to be stop with in 60 second.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
function myCalculator() {
    
        $(".container2").show();
        var start = 1000;
        var end = 10000;
     var duration = 2000;
        animateValue("value", start, end, duration); 
    }
    function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
        var range = end - start;
        var current = start;
        var increment = end > start? 11 : -1;
        var stepTime = Math.round(duration / range);
     var obj = document.getElementById(id);
        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            current += increment;
            obj.innerHTML = parseFloat(current).toLocaleString('en-US');
            if ((increment > 0 && current >= end) || (increment < 0 && current <= end)) {
                    obj.innerHTML = parseFloat(end).toLocaleString('en-US');
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
         }, stepTime);
      
          }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button name="submit" type="button" id="contact-submit" onclick="myCalculator();" >Click Here to See Animation</button>    
<div style="display:none;" class="container2">Animating Amount $ <span id="value" ></span></div>
```

Note:

If end value is small like 1,000 then this animation needs to be stop within 60 sec and if end value is large like 10,000,000 then this animation also needs to be stop in 60 sec. Please help me to fix it ?

Comment: Hey @Jasbir, I added an aswer, can you check to see if this helps you and upvote if yes? Thanks!

Comment: @CalvinNunes I have vote up to your answer but I am also expecting vote up to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy that you can follow is a timestamp when your animation starts and check how much time has passed to stop.

```js
function myCalculator() {

  $(".container2").show();
  var start = 1000;
  var end = 200000;
  var duration = 2000;
  animateValue("value", start, end, duration);    

 }

 function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
   var range = end - start;
   var current = start;
   var increment = end > start? 11 : -1;
   var stepTime = Math.round(duration / range);
   var obj = document.getElementById(id);
   //timestamp when animation starts
   var startTime = performance.now();
   var timer = setInterval(function() {
      current += increment;
      obj.innerHTML = parseFloat(current).toLocaleString('en-US');

      // this instruction check if has passed 60 seconds 
      // (performance.now() - startTime)/1000 > 60 ) 
      if ((increment > 0 && current >= end) || (increment < 0 && current <= end) || ((performance.now() - startTime)/1000 > 60 )) {
            obj.innerHTML = parseFloat(end).toLocaleString('en-US');
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
     }, stepTime);

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button name="submit" type="button" id="contact-submit" onclick="myCalculator();" >Click Here to See Animation</button>    
<div style="display:none;" class="container2">Animating Amount $ <span id="value" ></span></div>
```

this instruction check how much time has passed:

```
(performance.now() - startTime)/1000 > 60
```

Comment: I dont know what to do, Can you please fix it .?

Comment: @Jasbir, the solution is written in the code. Try copying and pasting

Comment: Sorry to say you @Jose, I tried many times but your script is not working, Even number is not animating

Comment: @Jasbir take a look of my edit, you have the code working

Comment: Yes, @Jose its working now, actually i missed the class which displaying the animation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jasbir If my answer helps you out, can you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I made a different aproach, take a look.
(I made it stop with 6 seconds to be easier to see it working, , change the var secondsLeft to adjust to your time)

```js
var timer;

function myCalculator() {    
    $(".container2").show();
    var start = 1000;
    var end = 10000;
    var duration = 2000;
    animateValue("value", start, end, duration); 
}

function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    var secondsLeft = 6000; 
    runTime(id, start, end, duration);
    setTimeout(function(){stopClock();}, secondsLeft);   
}
    
function runTime(id, start, end, duration){
    var range = end - start;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 11 : -1;
    var stepTime = Math.round(duration / range);
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = parseFloat(current).toLocaleString('en-US');            
    }, stepTime);
}

function stopClock(){
  clearInterval(timer);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button name="submit" type="button" id="contact-submit" onclick="myCalculator();" >
  Click Here to See Animation
</button>    
<div style="display:none;" class="container2">Animating Amount $ 
  <span id="value" ></span>
</div>
```